# FA icons displaying question mark

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

So, everything was working ok, but I was getting and js error for the extension woff2.

At this point, the web.Release.config had this code:

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
 </staticContent>
```

Then, to fix that error, I changed it to:

```
<system.webServer>
 <staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
  <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff" />
 </staticContent>
```

After that, my website only displays question marks instead of the correct icons. Even if I change it back.

I already update the fa version, restarted the iis, cleaned cache...
Also, in the iis, changed the extension and MIME types.
In Visual Studio, I tried to save the document in unicode.

Nothing worked.
In development it works, in production it doesnt.

New ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm that the font files are being loaded by the browser? And, are the correct content types being sent by the production server when serving the font files?

Comment: just checked the server, they are all being loaded correclty